# How can I get the bit error rate (BER) for a given connection?

Tags: networking, network-interface, internet, statistics

I would like to know the bit error rate (BER), calculated as (total good TX/RX bits)/(total good/bad TX/RX bits).

I have looked through available information from the rtnetlink library as well as the information available in /sys/class/net//statistics but I cant seem to find the information necessary to get this. Specifically I cant find error bits anywhere, but sys/class/net//statistics does contain total GOOD rx/tx bytes